# laravel route doesn't exist though it exits

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my route:

```
Route::post('admins.login', 'AdminsController@login');
```

This is my form

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admins.login', 'class' => 'loginClass', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

This is the exception:

```
Route [admins.login] not defined.
```

The method:

```
public function login(){
        echo "Save Time";exit;
    }
```

#### Edit

I already tried making `/` instead of `.` in all situations

Comment: Did you create the method in your AdminsController?

Comment: @Vucko yes I already didd

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes period.

Comment: @deczo I already tried to do `/` instead of `.` in all possibilities

Comment: bty why did you downvote this question? I had a problem and I tried to solve it and the prof is that I showed you all the things that should be used

Comment: I did not, and check my answer

Comment: @deczo I am not taking about you, I am taking about the guy who did that and didn't write the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route definition for a named route:

```
Route::post('admins/login', array('uses' => 'AdminsController@login', 'as' => 'admins.login'));
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admins.login', 'class' => 'loginClass')) }}
```

Comment: That works and **I am shocked**. I have this route `Route::get('restaurants/admins/{id}', 'RestaurantsController@admins');` and it is working, I did the same way but it doesn't work this time. why your code works? **why my previous code is working?**

Comment: Probably you don't call it as a named route anywhere, that's why. This particular would also work if you didn't use `route => admins.login` in the form but `url => admins/login`